# MXPlayer like volume control

Tags: android

I have a view on right side of the screen:

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/right_scroll">
</View>
```

I have hooked up a scroll event listener to it using:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Log.d("Gesture ", " onScroll");
        if (e1.getY() < e2.getY()){
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        }
        if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But this is changing the volume way too fast. Is there any way to slow this change in volume down like MXPlayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it. Doesn't work perfectly but gets the job done!

```
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        if (e1.getY() < e2.getY() ){
            volumeUp = 0;
            volumeDown += 1;
            if(volumeDown > 7) {
                Log.i("Increased", "Vol decrease");
                audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                volumeDown = 0;
            }
        }
        if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
            volumeDown = 0;
            volumeUp += 1;
            if(volumeUp > 7){
                Log.i("Increased", "Vol increase");
                audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
                volumeUp = 0;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```